# stop keypress event inside iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I am stuck with stoping the *ENTER* key on a input inside a iframe.

This works, crossbrowser, within the same page:

```
$("#input").keypress(function (event) {
    console.log(event.which); //works good
    if (event.which == 13) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

This **does not** work stoping/catching the keypress event inside the iFrame.

```
$("#my_iframe").contents().keypress(function (event) {
    console.log(event.which); // nothing loged
    if (event.which == 13) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

What am I missing? is there a crossbrowser solution?

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4gLQK/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not waiting for the iframe to load before attaching the event handler.

Comment: Hmmm... true. Thank you for the extra brain power to see that :)

Comment: Well, it took me too long I see. Stephen is right. But your fiddle also suffered from cross-domain security. Here's the complete and working solution http://jsfiddle.net/cM8yS/14/.

Comment: @mco, thank you for checking it too. Next time I will also think about this solution faster :) I edited my fiddle to remove the cross domain issue.

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to Stephen Thomas's answer, here's a nice article summing up what the problem is:

[Attaching an event to a form's elements inside an iframe with a use of jQuery](http://blazejklisz.pl/blog/article/attaching-an-event-to-a-forms-elements-inside-an-iframe-with-a-use-of-jquery)

However if you try to update your fiddle with new code, you'll most likely get an error, something along these lines:

`Blocked a frame with origin "http://fiddle.jshell.net" from accessing a frame with origin "http://jsfiddle.net". Protocols, domains, and ports must match`

Seems like jsfiddle uses two different servers for its internal workings and that is against the "Same Origin" policy - in short, you shouldn't be able to access DOM of iframes from different sites. As a measure of safety I guess. Though I don't know if you can actually skip it somehow. Cheers

Comment: Thank you for checking this also. I edited my fiddle so there are no cross domain problems anymore. The `http://` was the issues regarding that